# Listen to events on xbox gamepad - UWP

Tags: javascript, windows, uwp, xbox, gamepad

What is the correct way to listen on keypress events from the Xbox gamepad?

Buzzwords: UWP, HTML/CSS/JS, React, Typescript

Comment: The title says “set events” but you ask about “listen on keypress events”. Which do you want? You want to know how to listen to button presses from an Xbox gamepad, right?

Comment: I don't know much about JavaScript support on the Universal Windows Platform, but maybe the [Gamepad API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API) is available. Edge supports that API, at least.

Comment: This returns null :(

Answer (score 0):

You could first listen to the [GamepadAdded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.gamepad#Events) event. You would get the `Gamepad` class object by the event args when the the `GamepadAdded` event is fired.

Then, you could call its [GetCurrentReading()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.gamepad#Methods) method to get which button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try Xavier's method, we do it like this:

`const systemMediaControls = Windows.Media.SystemMediaTransportControls.getForCurrentView();
systemMediaControls.addEventListener('buttonpressed', eventHandler)`